# Is there a way to find the load time of Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to make a loading screen(Splash screen) for my Java SE app. And I am using Hibernate to as the ORM. The session factory creation takes sometime and I would like to know if there is a way to find how much time it takes for the Hibernate session factory to load?

Comment: Do you want to estimate session factory loading time before building SessionFactory? Or do you want just to load SessionFactory in separate Thread and show progress bar during SessionFactory building?     Meanwhile do you use Spring framework?

Comment: rather than showing the splash screen for some estimated time, why don't you show it, and hide it when the session factory has loaded?

Comment: yeah that option seems great I did the loading in a different thread--- I want to know if there was a easy way to get the load status of Hibernate Sessions... @savor I don't use Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible through an API so you'll have to use a workaround.

Possible solutions:

1. simply display an infinite loading spinner without caring of when the session factory loading will actually complete: [image]
2. keep track of the last 5 session factory load times, average them, and display a loader with that duration
3. instrument HbmBinder (with AOP or via direct code editing at the source of hib [not recommended]) and whenever it finishes mapping a class, update a static counter which you'll be able to access from another thread
4. start up the app with your own java based `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` and whenever you add a resource or class you will update the "classes loaded" counter